# Prevent system sleep/suspend with user-space application (like vlc)?

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I have had a need to run my computer as a server temporarily, and so I tried to prevent from Ubuntu 18.04 Settings that it sleeps - this failed, as I realized a day later the computer had its screen and wifi off, so probably some sort of sleep occurred.

So now I have slightly less trust in (my ability to set up) the Settings; on the other hand, I've noticed, that if I have say VLC player play a video on loop, the system tends to never go to sleep.

I'm not sure what it is exactly that VLC does - but is there an application I could use (with GUI or without), that I could run, and as long as it is running, it prevents system sleep - except without having to play video and sound? Basically, something I could start from the command line, leave it on (blocking the terminal) so it prevents sleep, - and in the end I either close the GUI window, or hit Ctrl-C in the terminal, to exit?